# How can I prevent new line when I am using loop and form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I prevent new line when I am using loop and form.I have tried `style="display: inline-block;"` but it didn't work. I would want buttons to be in one line ,next to each other.

```
<div>
    @foreach (range(1, 12) as $item)
            
        @if(App\Models\Seats::find($item))

            <form  method="post" action="{{ route('seats.destroy',  $item) }}">     
                @csrf
                @method('delete')
             
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="row_seats" value="4"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="seat_id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
                <button type="submit"  style="margin-left:10px; width:60px;"  class="btn btn-danger">{{$item}}</button>
            </form>
       
        @else
      
            <form method="post" action="/seats">
                @csrf 
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="row_seats" value="4"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="seat_id" value="{{  $item }}"/>
                <button type="submit"  style="width:60px; margin-left:10px;"  class="btn btn-success">{{ $item}}</button>
            </form>
             
        @endif
               
    @endforeach
        
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not posting rendered HTML and whatever CSS you have? There is nothing LARAVEL, PHP or JavaScript  related here. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/

Comment: Maybe a bootstrap CSS rule has an effect to the inputs, they're inline elements by default. Use the DevTools to find out which CSS rules are applied to the buttons. Actually, there's only a single visible button in the forms, how is that not placed in line ..?

Comment: I don't have CSS I only used bootstrap ,I tried with CSS but it doesn't work. I have 12 buttons not only 1 .

Comment: Please tag whatever templating that is.

Comment: I tried this but nothing  <form style="display: inline;" method="post" action="/seats"> and also `display:inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

I found decision of the problem this is my code if someone have the same problem. I used div with with `display:flex`

```
<div style="margin-left:90px;"  class="row pt-1 pb-1 ">
    <div style="display: flex;">
4 Ред
@foreach (range(1, 12) as $item)
@if(App\Models\Seats::find($item))

<form style="display: inline-block;" method="post" action="{{ route('seats.destroy',  $item) }}">
  
       
        @csrf
        @method('delete')
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}"/> -->
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="row_seats" value="4"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="seat_id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
        <button type="submit"   style="margin-left:10px; width:80px; display:inline;"  class="btn btn-danger">{{$item}}</button>


    </form>

            @else
      
        <form style="display: inline;" method="post" action="/seats">
   
        @csrf 
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}"/> -->
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="row_seats" value="4"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="seat_id" value="{{  $item }}"/>
            <button  type="submit"  style="width:80px; margin-left:10px;"  class="btn btn-success">{{ $item}}</button>
            
            
 
        </form> 

        @endif

@endforeach
</div>
</div>
```